# TabLayout fragment with two separate ListViews

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have an Activity that is a TabLayout. For the content, I have a Fragment; this Fragment holds a ListView. I wish to use the same Fragment for both tabs--but each have different ListViews. What is the best way to accomplish this? The lists both hold data retrieved from RottenTomatoes using their JSON API.

**RecentReleasesFragment.java**

```
public class RecentReleasesFragment extends Fragment {

    private ArrayAdapter<String> mMovieAdapter;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mDVDAdapter;
    private int mPage;
    public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";

    /**
     * Constructor for the RecentReleasesFragment
     * @param page fragment is on
     * @return newly created fragment
     */
    public static RecentReleasesFragment newInstance(int page) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, page);
        RecentReleasesFragment fragment = new RecentReleasesFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mPage = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recent_releases, container, false);

        switch(mPage) {
            case 1:
                FetchMovies taskMovie = new FetchMovies();
                taskMovie.execute();
                recentMoviesList(view);
            case 2:
                FetchDVDs taskDVD = new FetchDVDs();
                taskDVD.execute();
                recentDVDsList(view);
        }
        return view;
    }

    public void recentMoviesList(View v) {
        ListView mRecentMoviesList = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listview_recent_movies);
        mMovieAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                getActivity(),
                R.layout.list_item_film,
                R.id.list_item_film,
                new ArrayList<String>());
        mRecentMoviesList.setAdapter(mMovieAdapter);
    }

    public void recentDVDsList(View v) {
        ListView mRecentDVDsList = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listview_recent_movies);
        mDVDAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                getActivity(),
                R.layout.list_item_film,
                R.id.list_item_film,
                new ArrayList<String>());
        mRecentDVDsList.setAdapter(mDVDAdapter);
    }
    //adds items to mMovieAdapter
    public class FetchMovies extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> { . . . 
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
            if (result != null) {
                mMovieAdapter.clear();
                for (String movie : result) {
                    mMovieAdapter.add(movie);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    //adds items to mDVDAdapter
    public class FetchDVDs extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> { . . . }
}
```

**fragment_recent_releases.xml**

```
<ListView android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:id="@+id/listview_recent_movies"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
</ListView>
```

**RecentReleasesActivity.java**

```
public class RecentReleasesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Bind(R.id.toolbar) Toolbar toolbar;

    private SessionManager mSession;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recent_releases);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        this.mSession = SessionManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

        toolbar.setTitle(recentReleases);

        // Get the ViewPager and set it's PagerAdapter so that it can display items
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new RecentReleasesFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                RecentReleasesActivity.this));

        // Give the TabLayout the ViewPager
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.recent_releases_tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }
```

**activity_recent_releases.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/abl_top"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/recent_releases_tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/abl_top" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_recent_releases" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: You can use the same fragment for both the tabs and use two different adapters to provide different UI or you can even handle this with single adapter based on which tab you are in but its easier and cleaner if you have two different adapter.

Comment: The above code uses two separate adapters but the same ListView--both ListViews end up holding the same data.

Comment: In FetchMovies & FetchDVDs are you updating list with the received string[]  at onPostExecute method ?

Comment: Yep. The issue isn't getting the data, it's displaying the same ListView twice--both with different data. I've updated my OP with my `onPostExecute()` for one of the Fetchs

Comment: hmm.. just saw you are not having break in your switch case. if the case 1 executes then it also executes case 2 as well.

Comment: null pointer ? happening at which method ?

Comment: and that fixed it. Chalk it up to over thinking crap. :P Thank you!

Comment: great sometimes it happens :)